# What are the Curl SMTP command line arguments to support GMail TLS/STARTTLS vs SSL

Tags: email, ssl, curl, command-line, smtp

I am using Curl.exe in an application to send emails.  I need to support most major email servers.  GMail exposes the following ports and Authentication methods.

- TLS/STARTTLS (sometimes called Explicit TLS): uses port 587
- SSL (sometimes called Implicit TLS): uses port 465

I have gotten the Explicit TLS to work using the following command line:

```
C:\>curl smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587 -v --mail-from "my.mail@gmail.com" --mail-rcpt 
"your.mail@x.com" --ssl -u my.mail@gmail.com:password -T "c:\test.txt" -k --anyauth
```

I have tried the following to get ImplicitTLS to work, but it is not.

```
C:\>curl smtp://smtp.gmail.com:465 -v --mail-from "my.mail@gmail.com" --mail-rcpt 
"your.mail@x.com" --ssl -u my.mail@gmail.com:password -T "c:\test.txt" -k --anyauth
```

What are the proper command line parameters to get SSL/Implicit TLS to work?

Comment: You've swapped explicit/implicit: when you say *START* SSL/TLS, you tell it explicitly to start. Note that both can use SSL or TLS in general. (I wrote a [long answer on SF](http://serverfault.com/a/368574/47187) about this.)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I swapped the explicit and implicit descriptions.

Comment: Have you tried to use `smtps://...`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `smtps://` for SMTPS (i.e. SMTP on top of an existing SSL/TLS connection).

This works:

```
curl smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465 -v
```

I would also use `--ssl-reqd` for the explicit STARTTLS connection to make sure SSL/TLS is used when you expect it to be (downgrade attacks would be possible otherwise).

Don't use `-k` either, check the server certificate: see http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Answer (score 12):

well i just tried the following and it works fine:

```
curl smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465 -v --mail-from "xxx@gmail.com" --mail-rcpt "yyy@gmail.com" --ssl -u xxx@gmail.com:password -T "test.txt" -k --anyauth
```

hope it helps!

Comment: curl: (67) Login denied

Answer (score 2):

You can test using this command:

```
curl -v --url "smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465" --ssl-reqd   --mail-from "sender@gmail.com"   --user "sender@gmail.com" --mail-rcpt "sender@gmail.com"
```

You will have to **create a new 16 digits password** specific for this application and simply change the **account password** to this new secure **app password**. Now you can create one password for each app. It will keep your account password safe and manage app passwords separately.

Login to your account to create it:
https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords

You must enable the 2-Step Verification (https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/two-step-verification) to access this feature.

> To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no
> longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you
> to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and
> password.
>
> https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Answer (score 1):

Your can try this..

```
curl --url "smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465" --ssl-reqd --mail-from "sender@gmail.com" --mail-rcpt "recepient@gmail.com" --upload-file /var/scripts/mail.txt --user "sender@gmail.com:senderGmailPassword"
```